# Using PhoneGap Git Subversion

Tags: iphone, git, plugins, directory, cordova

I have started to write a plugin for PhoneGap and now I want to create a folder under IPhone directory inside [PhoneGap Plugins Git](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins). Is there a guide I can follow to create a directory for my Plugin so developers could contribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to:

- fork the [PhoneGap Plugins GitHub repo](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins), that is create a clone managed by you on the GitHub server side: see [GitHub help page on Fork a Repo](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/)
- clone that fork locally
- make your own folder with your plugin, and push it back to your GitHub fork, making it visible by all
- ask for developers to contribute to your own plugin, by forking themselves your own version of the PhoneGap Plugins project
- include any **[pull requests](http://help.github.com/pull-requests/)** from those developers
- once you are satisfied with your plugins and the developers contributions you have included, submit your own [pull request](http://help.github.com/pull-requests/) to the original project.

You create in essence an *intermediate* PhoneGap repo, which will collect all contributions (yours and other developers) for your own plugin, before submitting that new folder content back to the original [PhoneGap Plugins project](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins).

Comment: I forked and cloned the repository into my home folder and then added a folder to the iphone directory. Now am I supposed to push? any command? I am using "git push git@github.com:username/phonegap-plugins.git" but it's not working.

Comment: @Umair: a simple `git push origin master` should be enough, except if git port (9418) is somehow block. If that is the case, try cloning with `https://username@github.com/username/phonegap-plugins.git`: port 22 is rarely block.

Comment: @Umair: what `git remote -v` displays in your local git repo?

Comment: @Umair: ok, that means you are not locally within a git repo. You need to clone your GitHub repo first, then add, commit and push.

Comment: is there a definitive guide for Git which is short and precise I can read to do that? I am totally new to it.

Comment: @Umair: there is (even though it might be not so concise): http://library.edgecase.com/git_immersion/index.html . But the GitHub help pages are also great to begin to work with your GitHub repo: http://help.github.com/